# Cannot find namespace Microsoft.Azure in Visual Studio Mac

Tags: c#, .net, azure, xamarin-studio, visual-studio-mac

I'm trying out to create a simple DocumentDb hello world program and am getting `type or namespace name 'Azure' does not exist in namespace 'Microsoft'`

`using Microsoft.Azure`

I added the DocumentDb library via Nuget.  Do I need to manually add a reference to it after I add the nuget package?  I thought using nuget automatically adds the project references.

Answer (score 0):

According to your another [SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44310739/typeloadexception-with-documentclient-on-visual-studio-mac), it seems that you use the [.net project](https://www.microsoft.com/net/download/framework) not [.net core](https://www.microsoft.com/net/core/platform) project.

> The .NET Framework provides a comprehensive programming model for building all kinds of applications on Windows, from mobile to web to desktop.

Please have a try to creat a .net core project. 
We could get the [Microsoft.Azure.DocumentDB.Core](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Azure.DocumentDB.Core/) from nuget. I test creating a document on windows platform with **.net core** project. It works correctly on my side. I assume it should also work on Mac. The following is my demo code.

```
 var endpointUrl = "https://documentdbnamespace.documents.azure.com:443/";
 var authorizationKey = "xxxxxxxxxx";
 var databaseId = "database";
 var collectionId = "collection"; //I use an existing collect


 using (_client = new DocumentClient(new Uri(endpointUrl), authorizationKey))
    {
       var collectionLink = UriFactory.CreateDocumentCollectionUri(databaseId, collectionId);
       var product = new Product
          {
             Id= Guid.NewGuid().ToString(),
             ProductId = "test"
          };
       Document created =  _client.CreateDocumentAsync(collectionLink, product).Result;
     }
```

Product.cs Class :

```
 public class Product
    {
        [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "id")]
        public string Id { get; set; }

        // used to set expiration policy
        [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "ttl", NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore)]
        public int? TimeToLive { get; set; }

        public string ProductId { get; set; }
        public DateTime DateStarted { get; set; }
    }
```

[image]

We also could get more document example code from the [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/documentdb-sdk-dotnet-core).